# Strong Hold Without Shiny And Hard Hair

Tags: personal-care, hair

I'm new to this part of Stack and I have a question about hair that I've been wondering about.

I used a hair gel/glue called Spiker, found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XNZZLU) on Amazon.

Whenever I use this after getting out of the shower and drying my hair in the morning I use this stuff to give the front of my hair some volume.

This is fine but I must always use a good amount to make sure that it will stay up in the wind and if there's a little rain. However, at the end of the day after I've ran my hand through it a bit it is still in the same position but it's not as stiff and I can run my hands through it.

At this point it's not shiny or hard anymore, but it looks slightly worn in but still nice and I kind of want that for the morning. But if I actually sleep it just looks terrible in the morning haha.

Is there any trick to keep it as solid as it is in the morning but look like how it does in the afternoon?

Thanks!

Comment: to me this looks impossible, but maybe somebody will give any idea

Comment: Sounds like the product simply isn't the best one for you and you should experiment with other brands.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issues, switch from gel/mouse/spray to wax; wax gives a very strong hold with that dry look we want, **and** you can play around with it and it will remain how you leave it. [This](https://kingkabuz.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/axe_messylook.jpg) was my first wax and ever since I got it I haven't changed products, until recently where I moved outside the United States and getting a hold of it its hard, so I had to switch to something very similar.